# jQuery/WCF Web Application

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, wcf, json

Are there any VS template/Starter Kit/Any example of an ASP.NET Web Application, which uses jQuery and WCF (JSon), without ASP.NET Web Forms or ASP.NET Ajax, and generates clean code?

jQuery and C# for Web. No Web Forms/MVC. Is it actually possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely possible. You should start by using a [webHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.webscriptenablingbehavior.aspx) for your endpoint and naturally you need to apply the webHttp behavior as well. Then, when coding your WCF service, set the [ReqeustFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webinvokeattribute.requestformat.aspx)/[ResponseFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webinvokeattribute.responseformat.aspx) properties of the [WebGet/InvokeAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webinvokeattribute.aspx) which are applied to your operations.

From the jQuery perspective you can now call these methods using [the jQuery.ajax() API](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options) or any of the simpler variations (i.e. .load(), .get(), .post(), etc.). Obviously the method you use has to correlated with what HTTP method you've configured the service to expect.